# How to make jQuery validation plugin work for drop-down in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

jQuery validation plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ has an issue with drop-down in IE. I m using jQuery 1.7.2, Validation plugin 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.8.21.

Please see: http://quickshare.spreadsheet-converter.com/l/p/4jp8gq42fv57/

- in IE 7, the validation works i.e. it prevents form from submitting but the 'error' class is not applied. Though after being in invalid state, I can choose valid value. (though my IE 7 is **not** my concern.)
- in IE 8, the validation works, 'error' class is applied so I see 'red' border around. But, after being in invalid state, I can **not** open the drop-down - it automatically collapses. Though, I can double-click to choose valid value.
- in IE 9, the validation works, 'error' class is applied but I can not choose valid value after being in invalid state. The drop-down opens and closes automatically with single and double click. I also can not change values by using the left/right key - which is normally possible with drop-down.

Any hints?

Thanks!

UPDATE: The demo page http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html works for drop-down and the 'error' class is applied on invalid state too. Can it be related to CSS?

UPDATE 2: I tested in a plain page with both 1.9 and new release 1.10 of the validation plugin. I found that having **errorPlacement** object initialized like this was causing the problem. The problem goes away even if I comment the body function of **errorPlacement**. The demos on plugin website are not like this.

```
$('#formc').validate({      
    errorPlacement: function(error, element){               
        //$(element).attr({'title': error.text()});
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like IE does not like the title attribute on selects. In my case I am using bootstrap tooltips in the errorPlacement. My fix looks like this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(element).tooltip({ title: $(error).text(), container: 'body' });
        }
```

This just ignores setting the title attribute altogether. You could also determine if the element is a select and try some alternate option like this:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if($(element).is('select'){
                 ...do something else
                }
                else{
                    $(element).attr({'title': error.text()});
                }
        }
```